# How to pass SQL queries in json file?

Tags: java, sql, json, spring-boot

I'm creating dynamic application with spring boot. I want to get SQL queries from user to make changes without modifications of code. So I want to get it from json property file.

Is this a good approach ? Or there are alternative ways to do the same.

Comment: In theory it is possible approach and nothing wrong with it. Of course, if you are working on some kind of educational app. Otherwise I cannot see any other needs to give users ability to write raw SQL against DB on their own...

Comment: It's report generation module, where to client can select verbosity of report by setting condition query to select * query. This query only be applied to two tables containing logs.

Comment: OK you have SQL experienced users and do not care about SQL injection... then yes you can use Json file to keep let say "SQL template" (why not?)

Comment: But still, just a suggestion if it is about Production DBand there are more than those two tables or schemas available - to be more safe - give users ability to modify only certain fields in Select clause, (better prevent them to put SubSelects on their own there)  and modify some where clause conditions, but not all of them... I guess for that Json structure will serve that purpose good.